# Organization Service Create Entity returns "The unit id is missing"

Tags: c#, silverlight, dynamics-crm

I have a silverlight application which i'm using as a web resource for CRM 2015, I have used [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thecrmguys/archive/2012/08/28/silverlight-async-with-visual-studio-2012.aspx) tutorial to use async and await keywords. I can retrieve entities successfully. However, I'm trying to create entities into the CRM but for some reason I'm getting the error message "The unit id is missing".

I tried a very simple entity creation just for testing and still the same result, here is my code:

```
 Guid ProductCategoryGuid = new Guid(mytextblock.Tag.ToString());
                Money Amount= new Money();
                Amount.Value = Decimal.Parse(mytextblock.Text);

                EntityReference Opportunity = new EntityReference();
                Opportunity.Id = OpportunityGuid;
                Opportunity.LogicalName = "opportunity";

                EntityReference Product = new EntityReference();
                Product.Id = SelectedProductGuid;
                Product.LogicalName = "product";

                EntityReference ProductCategory = new EntityReference();
                ProductCategory.Id = ProductCategoryGuid;
                ProductCategory.LogicalName = "new_productcategory";

                Entity OpportunityProduct = new Entity();
                OpportunityProduct.LogicalName = "opportunityproduct";

                OpportunityProduct["new_productcategory"] = ProductCategory;
                OpportunityProduct["productid"] = Product;
                OpportunityProduct["opportunityid"] = Opportunity;
                OpportunityProduct["baseamount"] = Amount;

                await service.Create(OpportunityProduct);
```

EDIT:

I'm not sure if that helps, but I used Fiddler to debug my application and I got this Error: "**The unit id is missing**".

Comment: an opportunityproduct requires other attributes, like opportuntiyid and the productid if it's not a write-in product

Comment: @GuidoPreite I've updated my question with my original code that i've been testing, this contains the product and opportunity as well. I'm sure that the Guids provided for all entities exist in the crm since they have been retrieved from it originally.

Comment: try the code with a simple console application, if the console application works means that the problem is with silverlight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out I hadn't added the uom id for the opportunity product. I retrieved the defaultuomid of the product i'm referring to in the OpportunityProduct and then creation was completed successfully